# Tallying records using annotate() not working as should

Tags: django, annotations

I have two classes: `Vehicle` and `Issues`....a `Vehicle` object can have several issues recorded in the `Issues` class.  What I want to do is to have a list of all issues, with each vehicle appearing only once and the total number of issues shown, plus other details....clicking on the record will then take the user to another page with all those issues for a selected vehicle shown in detail now.

I tried this out using `annotate`, but I could only access the count and vehicle foreign key, but none of the other fields in the `Vehicle` class.

```
class Issues(models.Model):
   vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)
   description = models.CharField('Issue Description', max_length=30,)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Other')
   status = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='Pending')
   priority = models.IntegerField(default='8', editable=False)
   date_time_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today, editable=False)
   last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today, editable=False)
   def __unicode__(self):    
     return self.description
```

The code I was using to annotate is:

```
issues = Issues.objects.all().values('vehicle').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: "What I want to do is to have a list of all issues, with each vehicle appearing only once and the total number of issues shown"

This is not making any sense. You cannot have a list of all issues with each vehicle appaearing only once, when there are multiple issues per vehicle... it's the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do, should be queried the other way around, like this:

```
vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all().annotate(count_issues=Count('issues__pk'))
```

Now you'll have a queryset of Vehicle objects, thus you have all vehicle fields. And you'll have an extra field 'count_issues' for each vehicle.

**Edit**:
You can simply use a filter on the extra column from annotate:

```
vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all().annotate(count_issues=Count('issues__pk')).filter(count_issues__gt=0)
```

Comment: @ Botondus: sorry for the late reply....it worked just fine.  BTW what if I want to limit the query to only vehicle objects that have entries in the issues table?

Comment: You can simply filter by issues count, as I've added in my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

You've specifically requested to only have the vehicle in the returned queryset, via the call to `values`, so why are you surprised when that is indeed the result?